# Replacing a large String in groovy

Tags: java, string, groovy, replace

I am trying to replace a large string in groovy. But can't get it to work. I am using groovy 1.8.6

```
def textn = "http://10.33.0.69:8001/VS_SiteFacilityLookup/SiteFacilityLookupService?XSD=/com/enbridge/csim/ebo/module/common/serviceinterface/SiteFacilityLookupService.xsd"
textn = textn.replaceAll("http://10.33.0.69:8001/VS_SiteFacilityLookup/SiteFacilityLookupService?XSD=/com/enbridge/csim/ebo/module/common/serviceinterface/SiteFacilityLookupService.xsd", "hola")
println "textn : $textn"
```

This prints out the original variable

If I replace a shorter string, it replaces it correctly.

```
def textn = "http://10.33.0.69:8001/VS_SiteFacilityLookup/SiteFacilityLookupService?XSD=/com/enbridge/csim/ebo/module/common/serviceinterface/SiteFacilityLookupService.xsd"
textn = textn.replaceAll("SiteFacilityLookupService.xsd", "hola")
println "textn : $textn"
```

This prints out the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this pattern:

`http:\/\/10.33.0.69:8001\/VS_SiteFacilityLookup\/SiteFacilityLookupService\?XSD=\/com\/enbridge\/csim\/ebo\/module\/common\/serviceinterface\/SiteFacilityLookupService.xsd`

you need to remember to escape special characters - for e.g. `?` -> `\?`

so, to sum up, it ends as:

```
def textn = "http://10.33.0.69:8001/VS_SiteFacilityLookup/SiteFacilityLookupService?XSD=/com/enbridge/csim/ebo/module/common/serviceinterface/SiteFacilityLookupService.xsd"
textn = textn.replaceAll("http:\/\/10.33.0.69:8001\/VS_SiteFacilityLookup\/SiteFacilityLookupService\?XSD=\/com\/enbridge\/csim\/ebo\/module\/common\/serviceinterface\/SiteFacilityLookupService.xsd", "hola")
println "textn : $textn"
```

I have tested it here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

On the topic: While replacing Strings, in groovy, Java, and (I hope!) in any other language, String length doesn't matter. What does matter is that in larger pattern it's easier to omit something that will result in NO match. So you sould be using patterns that are simple, and easy to understand by the reader of code.

for example:

`http:\/\/.*` - matches every String that starts with `http://`

Comment: is there no way to force it to a string match rather than a pattern match? The value is inside a variable that I retrieve so I don't have the chance to do all the escaping.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, what is `replaceAll` first argument? String or regex? In Java it's regex (written as string) so despite using `" "` you still need to form good pattern -> escape special characters and so on.

Comment: @user1459777 Use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`. Replace works on String.